# GETDATE in Snowflake in not working for conversion

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

In SQL we can do below

```
select convert(varchar, getdate(), 101)
```

Anything same in Snowflake for GETDATE ?

Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

How about using CURRENT_DATE?

```
SELECT TO_VARCHAR(CURRENT_DATE, 'MM/DD/YYYY' ) ,
       TO_VARCHAR(CURRENT_DATE, 'DD-MM-YYYY' );
```

Comment: I want to format it like MM/DD/YYYY OR DD-MM-YYYY